# J1301 and J1302 external antenna connector on Coral SoM

Tags: google-coral

I searched but could not find any documentation describing how to use those external antenna connectors on Coral SoM. I suppose one is for WIFI and another one is for BlueTooth? or primary and diversity?
After some search, I found that those tiny connectors are Murata mm8930-2600 type. Is there any cable assembly available anywhere? I found none on most of the major distributors.
Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

The J1301/J1302 are mounted with the RF switch "Murata MM8930-2600" and you can attach an external antenna, but you have to use Murata's dedicated male connector. Another option is that you can remove the J1301/J1302 and solder Antenna's RF cable directly to the pad.

Answer (score 0):

J1301/J1302 are 50ohm U.FL. male connectors. You can use a [U.FL. female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxX6Z.png) to [SMA male](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dcuE.png) cable ( depend on what kind of Antenna you are using). One example is [this one](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/amphenol-rf/095-902-516-100/10261191), please make sure that the SMA end matches your antenna type. Some times you [need some adapters](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/amphenol-sv-microwave/SF2997-6003/6201798)

Yes you can solder directly to the PCB after removing the U.FL. connector, but be careful, since this affect the impedance matching and results in reflection loss.

Also keep an eye on the EIRP, since a high gain antennas may radiate more power than the power limit proposed by the regulatory authority in your country.